# Why is PropertyChangedEventHandler null?

Tags: c#, binding, silverlight-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

The mainpage:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
</Canvas>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
List<Usol> list = new List<Usol>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var element = new Usol();
    list.Add(element);
    Canvas.SetTop(element, i * 25);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(list[i]);
    }
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.context.name = "Varken";
}
```

A usercontrol

**Usol.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</Grid>
```

**Usol.xaml.cs**

```
 public Context context;
 public Usol()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     context = new Context();
     this.DataContext = context;
 }
```

A class

**Context.cs**

```
public class Context : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }       
    #region Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// Field Declaration for the <see cref="Name"/>
    /// </summary>
    private string name;
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Situation**

I have created this small test application to copy a problem I have in a bigger application. It works about the same way (not exactly, but close enough).

It adds several custom made usercontrols and each get a own instance of a datacontext class.

However, none of the properties are willing to update themselfs due to a empty `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.

**Question**

Why is `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` always null?

Comment: Just a suggestion. You are not following the expected field/property name conventions.

Comment: Do you mean that nobody subscribes? That's the behaviour I would expect if you use OneTime binding.
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" />. This also happens if you don't have define the interface (e.g. the event is there, but the class define it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong,

```
OnPropertyChanged("Name"); <-- should update "name" not "Name"
```

You are firing event saying that "Name" is changed, but name of property is "name", C# and binding are case sensitive.

Change it to,

```
#region Fields
/// <summary>
/// Field Declaration for the <see cref="name"/>
/// </summary>
private string _Name;
#endregion
#region Properties
/// <summary>
/// Gets or Sets the name
/// </summary>
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (this._Name != value)
        {
            this._Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

From  C# 6 on wards, please use `nameof()` keyword...

```
#region Fields
/// <summary>
/// Field Declaration for the <see cref="name"/>
/// </summary>
private string _Name;
#endregion
#region Properties
/// <summary>
/// Gets or Sets the name
/// </summary>
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        if (this._Name != value)
        {
            this._Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Fixed typo: fixed problem in this application. However in my "bigger" application I still have a similar problem where I am sure the bindings are done properly. Will take some time to investigate my problem further

Answer (score 2):

Context.cs needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Are you doing that?

Edit: Post your update.

I have generally seen this kind of problem when programmers create "two" instances of Model/ViewModel. While you attach one instance with View, it's always the other one that gets update (which ofcourse will have a null PropertyChanged subscribers). Thus, you must make sure that your view is using the same instance as being updated at other parts.
Hope my point is clear.

Comment: public class Context : INotifyPropertyChanged. Yes, Updated question with the proper information. Thank you for pointing out I forgot to add that in my question.

Comment: I've come across some of these answers on the net and I understand the problem. But what I don't understand is how silverlight can expect 2 instances. Even if it would so that only 1 instance can be used for binding atleast one of the PropertyChanged should have had a value since all 10 that are being created are bound to a view.